# Importing wordpress database, SQL error in phpMyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, syntax-error

I need help with this

Requête SQL :

```
CREATE TABLE `np_commentmeta` (
  `meta_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `comment_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `meta_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_value` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci


MySQL a répondu: Documentation

#1273 - Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci'
```

What is the problem with this SQL request while importing my database ?

Note: i'm working with french version of PhpMyadmin

Comment: Where's the question?

Comment: the question was the error i'm having ; #1273 - Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collation are only relevant for ordering table's data. If your importing/exporting data, I would say just try replacing `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` with `utf8_general_ci`.